# Scrapy CrawlSpider Rule not being followed?

Tags: regex, scrapy

My scrapy spider is crawling the forums, but I don't want it to.

The rules are in a json file:

```
"rules": [
{
    "allow": ["\\/topic\/.*"],
    "follow": true
},
{
    "allow": ["\\/tr\\/article\\/.*.html"],
    "follow": false,
    "use_content": true
},
{
    "deny": ["\/forum\/.*"],
    "follow": false
},
```

My spider is loading the json file and parsing the rules.
The allow and use_content are working, my forum rule seems to be ignored.

```
        # add all rules from JSON file in a for loop:
        deny_r = ()
        if "deny" in rule.keys():
            deny_r = [d for d in rule["deny"]]

        Genspider.rules.append(Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=allow_r,
                deny=deny_r,
                restrict_xpaths=restrict_xpaths_r,
            ),
            follow=rule["follow"],
            callback='parse_item' if ("use_content" in rule.keys()) else None
        ))
```

There are quite a few:

> 2018-12-31 07:45:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.example.com/forum/online/News-...

I assume my regular expression is wrong for avoiding /forum/ urls?
(tried several `["\/forum/.*"], [".*forum.*"], ["\/forum.*"]`but it seems to be always the same issue - other deny / follow false seem to be working though)

Comment: A quick question: are those `https://www.example.com/forum/online/News-*` pages linked *directly from some existing page*, or result of redirections (e.g. a page links to https://www.example.com/f?pid=foobar which redirects to https://www.example.com/forum/post?id=foobar):

Comment: These forum pages are linked from several pages, some that I do follow and want to scrape.

Comment: I'm confused; you're saying your log contains "crawler../forum/" so that means those pages are being crawled. What is your expected behaviour here?

Comment: I don't want to crawl them. Maybe the `follow = False` and `deny` would still crawl one page and not crawl anymore links? But I assumed if a link contains `forum`, it should be disregarded in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add deny to all the rules. Why?

As described in [Rule documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=Rule#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules)

> rules : Which is a list of one (or more) Rule objects. Each Rule defines a certain behavior for crawling the site. Rules objects are described below. If multiple rules match the same link, the first one will be used, according to the order they’re defined in this attribute.

So if any of first two rules apply to forum URLs it will be followed unless a deny entry is defined for it.

Your rules JSON should look like this

```
"rules": [
{
    "deny": ["\/forum\/.*"],
    "allow": ["\\/topic\/.*"],
    "follow": true
},
{
    "deny": ["\/forum\/.*"],
    "allow": ["\\/tr\\/article\\/.*.html"],
    "follow": false,
    "use_content": true
}
]
```

Comment: It sounds good but seems to be still not working. I've tried it like you suggested and in this case, the spider won't parse anything .. just crawl but not parse.